# How to secure data model classes from reverse engineering when using R8 and Proguard in Android?

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8, android-obfuscation

Right now, on reverse engineering the android application APK file, I can see the data model classes in the plain text as I have used `@keep` annotation. Without the annotation, the app is crashing as these files are being removed by the R8.

How do I secure the data model files by making sure that they are not seen on reverse engineering?

Comment: Can you give more information on what kind of data model class you are using? Do you use libraries like GSON ? Were you experiencing this same crash on Proguard also, or did it just appear after migrating to R8?

Comment: The data model classes are POJOs. Yes, I'm using GSON for deserializing server responses(which are json strings) to java objects. No, I didn't experience crashes when using Proguard.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have run into this same issue and my certain problem was I had an obsolete set of proguard rules. Note that on 4 Oct 2019 Gson updated their proguard rules to take R8 into account. Hopefully you have to update them.

You can find it at  https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

Also remember to add your certain model classes: look at the rule at the center as it is just an example and have to be changed with your own models.

Answer (score -1):

add below lines to `gradle.properties` file.

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false
# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this answers OP's question?